# Переход между введенными командами в MySql консоли

Tags: консоль, mysql

Работаю с mysql в консоли. Например создаю таблицу:

```
mysql> create table some_table (
-> id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
-> char_row char(50), 
->
```

И где-то в этом месте мне приходит в голову, что мне надо изменить в строчке
`"id int unsigned not null auto_increment,"` `id` на `test_id`. Могу ли я как-то подняться вверх и изменить или необходимо будет по новой писать запрос?

Comment: Если присмотреться, то таблицу я никак не мог создать ибо нет как минимум ";". О существовании ALTER TABLE я в курсе. Вопрос конкретно в том, можно ли в момент составления запроса возвращаться на строчку вверх.

Answer (score 1):

Собственно ответ тут: [MySQL console + Vi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/66656/178576).

Comment: От себя добавлю, что-бы было немного понятнее:

    mysql> create table some_table (
    -> id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    -> char_row char(50), 
    -> \e <Нажать Enter>

Answer (score 0):

ты же уже создал таблицу, что бы изменить имя колонки, есть специальная команда alter

```
Alter table table_name change old_column_name  new_column_name type size
```