# MySQL console + Vi

Tags: vi, консоль, mysql

Уже задавал вопрос по поводу редактирования многострочных запросов в mysql из под консоли. Решение нашел - vi. Но к сожалению, ввиду малого опыта, не смог довести идею до конца. Вопрос следующий: как вернуть результат из редактора vi обратно в mysql консоль? Т.е.
пишу запрос, в конце указываю e, редактирую запрос... И что дальше?

Comment: Для начинающего vi сложноват, может проще вам использовать mcedit? Ну а если, таки, решили изучать vi, то тогда изучите го на минимальном уровне см. [ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Vim][1]

  [1]:http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Vim

Comment: Я то изучил, но, надо сказать, поверхностно. Собственно, меня смущало то, что при редактировании файла не было видно результата в консоли mysql. И опять же, я непротив использовать mcedit, но к сожалению не знаю как. Впринципе, запомнил с десяток основных комманд в vi и хватает, но если кто-нибудь подскажет как это изменять запрос с помощью mcedit я буду только рад.

Comment: до запуска mysql, сделать: `export EDITOR=/usr/bin/mcedit` ну или в login script это записать, что-бы навсегда :-)

К сожалению не не знаю конкретики, но я обычно когда работаю с удаленной машиной по ssh, еще пару-тройку туннелей туда пробрасываю, например тогда удобно использовать GUI приблуды локальной машины для работы с SQL серверами и не только.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выйти из `vi` с сохраннением:

```
<ESC>ZZ
```

В mysql это выглядит так:

```
mysql> \e
    -> \g
```

Между `\e` и `\g` запускается `vi` где вы редактируете запрос